Is this the correct matrix expression of the affine transformation?
I'm working on an optimization method that deals with affine invariance property. I'm not well versed on linear algebra so I would like to verify if I understood the following correctly (taken from a work I'm reading).
This is a probability distribution function followed by its visualization (with $\epsilon=5$)
\begin{align}
\pi(x)\propto \exp \left(\frac{-(x_1-x_2)^2}{2\epsilon}-\frac{(x_1+x_2)^2}{2}\right).\label{eq:pdf}
\end{align}

The following is a supposed result from affine transformation applied to the space.
\begin{align}
 \pi_A(y)\propto\exp\left(\frac{-(y_1^2+y_2^2)}{2}\right)\label{eq:pdfeasy}
\end{align}

My question is, are the following lines a correct mathematical expression of the affine transformation applied?
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol {Ax}&=\boldsymbol y\\
\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt\epsilon}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt\epsilon}\\1&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 x_1\\x_2
\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{x_1-x_2}{\sqrt\epsilon}\\x_1+x_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
